# Set-AzAksCluster upgrade AKS Cluster

Tags: azure-aks, azure-powershell

Trying to get/print the current version of Aks cluster and checking which Kubernetes upgrade releases are available in the region where my AKS cluster resides and upgrading my AKS cluster. Below is my script where unable to upgrade from 1.23.12 to 1.24.3,hence its going to downgrading version(1.23.8). Hope you can assist me with a problem trying to execute a script block. Thanks in Advance

```
Param 
    (    
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] 
        $AKSName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] 
        $SubscriptionID
     )
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity > $null
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionID > $null

    $AKsResourceGroup= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.ResourceGroupName}
    
    $AKsLocation= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.Location}
    

#Check Current Version Of Cluster
$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion -WarningAction Ignore #> $null
 "The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion" | ConvertTo-Json

#Check the availability versions to upgrade
$Versions = Get-AzAksVersion -Location $AKsLocation | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt $CurrentVersion) -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion} -WarningAction Ignore
"These are the available versions $Versions" | ConvertTo-Json

$attempt3 =$versions.Replace(' ', ' , ')
$attempt3=$attempt3.replace(' " ' , " ")
$attempt3=$attempt3.replace(" ' "," ")
#for upgrading the latest version
$finalversion=$attempt3.Split(",")[0]

#AKS Upgrade
Set-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName -KubernetesVersion $finalversion -WarningAction Ignore > $null

#To check the status of AKS
Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | Format-Table -Property Name, Location, KubernetesVersion, ProvisioningState 
``
output:
"The CurrentVersion is 1.23.12"
"These are the available versions 1.23.8 1.24.3 1.24.6"
**Downgrading Kubernetes version 1.23.12 to 1.23.8 is not allowed. Available upgrades: 1.24.3,1.24.6.**
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to upgrade the AKS cluster version in my environment and got the below results***

> ***I have followed the below steps to upgrade the AKS cluster version***

```
$RG-name= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.ResourceGroupName}
    
$AKsLocation= Get-AzResource -Name $AKSName | foreach {$_.Location}

$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $RG-name -Name $AKSName | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion -WarningAction Ignore #> $null
"The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

> ***To check what are versions available in the cluster***

```
$Version = Get-AzAksVersion -Location $AKsLocation | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt $CurrentVersion) -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion} -WarningAction Ignore
"These are the available versions $Versions" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

> ***To Upgrade the version I have followed the below commands***

```
$final =$version.Replace(' ', ' , ')
$final=$final.replace(' " ' , " ")
$final=$final.replace(" ' "," ")
#for upgrading the latest version
$finalversion=final.Split(",")[1]

#AKS Upgrade
Set-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $RG-name -Name $AKSName -KubernetesVersion $finalversion -WarningAction Ignore > $null
```

> ***When I check the below command I am able to see the updated version***

```
Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $RG-name -Name $AKSName | Format-Table -Property Name, Location, KubernetesVersion, ProvisioningState
```

[image]

***Note:***
We will get the upgraded version based on the available versions, I have used the split function *split[1]* because I need the next version of my current version if we need **1.24.6** version we have to use *split[2]* array function.

Comment: Thanks @Komali Annem, but in my case trying to upgrade one by one (automating) ex: if my aks current version is in 1.22.15 first it should upgrade to 1.23.8 nd then 1.23.12 then 1.24.3, for that im collecting the list of available versions to upgrade the next version.....  everytime  cannot change spilt function.

Comment: @Usha thanks for the reply, when we check the available versions it is showing  3 versions one is for previous version and second one is for upgrade version and third one is for next available version, at a time we can upgrade to one version only, if we give this in automation account it will upgrade to the next available versions