# Workload identity with application on Kubernetes service:kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy and manage the Kubernetes cluster using OpenID Connect issuer, I have followed this [Microsoft Document to deploy the application on AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/tutorial-kubernetes-workload-identity) for that I have created the resource group and install the AKS preview extension

```
`az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus
az extension add --name aks-preview
az extension update --name aks-preview

#register the enabled workload identity
az feature register --namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService" --name "EnableWorkloadIdentityPreview"az feature show --namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService" --name "EnableWorkloadIdentityPreview"
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService`
```

After that when I am trying to create the Kubernetes cluster with `--enable-oidc-isser` I am getting below error, it is taking more than 10 minutes and showing some error

`(OIDCIssuerUnsupportedk8sVersion) OIDC issuer feature requires at least Kubernetes version 1.20.0. Code: OIDCIssuerUnsupportedK8sVersion Message: OIDC issuer feature requires at least Kubernetes version 1.20.0`

I have upgraded to the latest version but still getting same error.
How can I export OIDC Issuer to set the Environment variables on the cluster.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

> My current version is 1.23.12

[image]

*I have created the resource group and install the extension preview and registered the **`EnabledworkloadidentityPreview`**  using below command*

```
az feature register --namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService" --name "EnableWorkloadIdentityPreview"
```

[image]

*To verify the status used the below command*

```
az feature show --namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService" --name "EnableWorkloadIdentityPreview"
```

*I have created the AKS cluster with `--enable-oidc-issuer` parameter to use the OIDC issuer using below command*

```
az aks create -g rg -n cluster --node-count 1 --enable-oidc-issuer --enable-workload-identity --generate-ssh-keys
```

> *When I check in my environment and got the same error*

[image]

*To resolve this issue I have upgraded my AKS version using below commands*

> My current version is **1.23.12**

[image]

*I have upgraded the to newest version using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74700285/set-azakscluster-upgrade-aks-cluster/74716094#74716094)*

[image]

*My current version is 1.24.3 and when I the below OIDC command I am able access*

```
az aks create -g <rg-name> -n cluster --node-count 1 --enable-oidc-issuer --enable-workload-identity --generate-ssh-keys
```

[image]

***NOTE:*** This error will occur if the version is more than 1.20.0 we have to upgrade the version to latest version not to current version then only it will work